# How to create an Installer which installs SQL Server without Internet connection

Tags: installshield

Could any one guide me through the steps to create an Installer using **InstallShield-2021** which will install 'SQL Server Express 2019' on a target machine **WITHOUT Internet Connection**.

Thanks and Regards

Aslam

Comment: On a machine with internet connection, download the installer at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866658, launch it and you will have the choice to download binaries that you can use on a computer with no internet connection

Answer (score 0):

In Installation Designer tab of Installshield, browse for:

Application Data > Redistributables > Find 'SQL Server Express 2019' > Right click 'Download it' > Check the checkbox